# node and nginx cacheng issue for mongodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx

I am using AWS, nginx server. If I update or create data in mongodb using nodejs api the data is storing and I am getting the success response.. But when I am trying to get data through postman it's returning old data. and that data is getting updated after 15 or 20 min later. But if I check data through using Sudo mongo the updated data is showing.. Why this problem is happening.. Please give me a solution if any one knows..[The down image is nginx configured file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld1f2.png)